# Access a local variable from a callback function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update a local variable in a function with the returned data from a callback function. But it's looking like the callback function doesn't have access to it.

Below is what I'm working with:

```
this.renderUI = function(res) {
    var connected = (res.user != null && res.user.isConnected);
    if(connected) {
      $j('#jive-modal-invite').trigger('close'); 
      var contactsData = gigya.socialize.getContacts({callback: getContacts_callback });
      console.log(contactsData);  
    }else {
      console.log('openid disconnected');
    }   
  };

  function getContacts_callback(response) {
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: The callback is asynchronous, so it does not know about the local variable.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why is your callback like: `gigya.socialize.getContacts({callback: function(response){` instead of `gigya.socialize.getContacts(function(response){`?

Comment: If `getContacts` is asynchronous, you simply cannot (and should not). Put the logging statements (and everything else the accesses `contactsData`) in the callback

Comment: @Bergi I can't access global variables from the callback either. Is this a known behaviour?

Comment: @drecute: Of course you can if they're really global.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(contactsData);` is being executed before your callback is complete try this:

```
  gigya.socialize.getContacts({callback: function(response){
    contactsData['contacts'] = response;
    console.log(contactsData); 
  } });
```

Comment: I need `contactsData` outside of the callback scope

Comment: How about calling a function from inside your callback?